# How to change tooltip formatting in windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Have not been able to change tooltip formatting in windows 10 so as to instigate a default format for comments in excel. This use to be simple with previous versions using advanced appearance settings which I have not been able to find in windows 10. Help??

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I could find is posted at;
http://www.askvg.com/how-to-access-advanced-appearance-settings-option-to-change-text-size-in-windows-8/
One needs access to a computer running Win7 so as to make the necessary changes using advanced appearance settings, after which one transfers the saved registry files (as described at link) to a usb disk from which they are incorporated into the pc running Win10. Restart the computer and Voila; Problem solved.

Should be an easier way MicroSoft??